# How to read raw image in Python and plot as an image

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, computer-vision, hough-transform

I am trying to read a raw image file, but the stored image array seems to be one dimensional. Not sure how to read a raw file and plot it. Any help would be appreciated

Link to image [TestImage1c.raw](https://drive.google.com/open?id=12LcQZyYWMg9_6T_n3gjy7kBadRGNMDdr)

```
from scipy import misc
from scipy import ndimage
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import math

A = np.fromfile("TestImage1c.raw", dtype='int16', sep="")
print("A.shape: %d", A.shape)
print("A: ", A)
img_gray = np.dot(A[..., :3], [0.30, 0.59, 0.11])
print("img_gray :", img_gray)
print("img_gray shape: ", img_gray.shape)
print("img_gray size: ", img_gray.size)
plt.imshow(img_gray, cmap="gray")
plt.show()

OUTPUT:

D:\Python36\python.exe D:/PycharmProjects/First/readrawimage.py
A.shape: %d (1143072,)
A:  [-27746 -24987  26514 ...,  28808 -31403  18031]
img_gray : -20149.59
img_gray shape:  ()
img_gray size:  1
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:/PycharmProjects/First/readrawimage.py", line 33, in <module>
    plt.imshow(img_gray, cmap="gray")
  File "D:\Python36\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\pyplot.py", line 3080, in 
  imshow
    **kwargs)
  File "D:\Python36\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\__init__.py", line 1710, in 
  inner
    return func(ax, *args, **kwargs)
  File "D:\Python36\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes\_axes.py", line 5194, 
  in imshow
    im.set_data(X)
  File "D:\Python36\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\image.py", line 604, in 
  set_data
    raise TypeError("Invalid dimensions for image data")
TypeError: Invalid dimensions for image data

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: Thanks for the feedback.

It was a raw image, so no preview for image and didn't upload first time. Although I have added a link now.

Comment: Is it a `RAW` image in the sense of a "digital negative"?  every camera manufacturer has its own format, so you have to provede details.  Further, in a `.raw` file there is always a header part that cannot be dealt with `np.fromfile`

Comment: Its a raw image and its pixel are in the interleaved manner.


R(0,0) G(0,0) B(0,0)
R(1,0) G(1,0) B(1,0)
R(2,0) G(2,0) B(2,0)

Answer (score 3):

I found that RAW file is interleaved with RGB value an is one dimensional array

R(0,0) G(0,0) B(0,0) 
R(0,1) G(0,1) B(0,1)

.......

```
A = np.fromfile("TestImage2c.raw", dtype='int8', sep="")

A = np.reshape(A, (756, 1008, 3))
img_gray = np.dot(A[..., :3], [0.30, 0.59, 0.11])
plt.imshow(img_gray, cmap="gray")
plt.show()
```

I started getting the image now.

Thank you all for response.

Comment: for me, A = np.fromfile(img, dtype='int32', sep="") worked for grayscale IR images. Thankyou :)